# How to Clip/Threshold based on a coordinate function f(x,y,z)?

Tags: paraview

I have noisy 3D structured data of a cylinder. I'd like to clip/threshold the data such that data inside or outside of a certain radius is ignored. I.e. segment based on `f > or < sqrt((coordX - X0)^2 + (coordY - Y0)^2)`, where `X0` and `Y0` are configurable, or at least the center of the `X/Y` dataset. Is there an intuitive way to do this?

I can calculate f using the calculator filter, but don't know how to use the results in a filter to segment out the original data.

Can I use a cylinder source to segment a dataset inside/outside of the cylinder?

Or would it be best to program my own Python filter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can calculate the function which defines the region to keep or to exclude,
then applying the threshold filter or a succession of 2 clip filters (remember to change the clip type to scalar and to use once the inside out option) should be enough.

Just a tip, I have different behaviors with these two options if my data has only one cell (like a line) or if my data has one cell on each point (like after applying the vertex glyph filter)

Comment: Thanks, lib. That makes sense, but I'd like to use the values of the original dataset, at the locations of the thresholded/clipped calculated function. Ie, show the intensities of the original dataset where calculated function R is > or < a certain value.

Reading into this, it's sounding like the Python calculator may be the best way to do this.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the problem, but if you compute R as a point/cell data array (e.g with the calculator) and then threshold by R you get an unstructured grid with the points and cells (and associated arrays) satisfying the threshold condition. But also the calculator is a option, for example if you want the mean of the array V at location with R>2 you can do mean(V[R>2]). Otherwise you can clip with a sphere or a box, but no cylinder in the paraview clip filter (unless you code in the programmable filter a vtkclipper with cylinder source)

Comment: In using your answer, I would get an unstructured grid with points satisfying the threshold condition, but the result would only contain the value of R, < or > the threshold. What I want is to have the values of the original dataset displayed (eg. from 0-255), at the locations where R is > or < the threshold. So in your answer, I would only see values of the calculated result ranging from eg. R1 - R2. But I'd like to see values of the original dataset, eg. 0-255, but only in locations of R from R1-R2. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Wait, I just found out that the calculated output contains both the calculated result and input values as attributes. And I can threshold based on the input values, from the calculated filter. That makes sense, that works. Thanks!